# vim does not see lib directory in projects

Tags: macvim

Learning Ruby, using MacVim on Mountain Lion.

Installed Command-T (same problem if I used CtrlP) and a file search is not finding the lib directory. That's how I noticed it, but it's not seen anywhere by anything vim related.

If I go to a project directory that contains a lib subdirectory and start vim with 'mvim .', the directory listing does not show lib. If I invoke NerdTree, lib does not show up.

Weird. But from what little I know about Ruby at this point, it seems ruby files are supposed to go under lib so I need to get this working.

Ideas?

Comment: what does `:!ls` say?

Comment: :!ls shows lib. None of the plugin's do.

Comment: and what about `echo NERDTreeIgnore` and similar settings in the other plugins ctrlp and command-t. It seems to be a plugin related problem. Is the lib folder in particular very large that the plugins do not consider it for performance reasons.

Comment: I found it - starring me right in the face. set wildignore+=lib for Clojure. An augroup is in my future.